# How to read a file a text file line by line and store each line in an array using android? Can an xls file be read in android?

Tags: android

Actually I wanna use the contents of the file to trigger an alarm.

Answer (score 1):

try this snippet!

```
try {
  InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("myfile.txt");

if (inputStream != null) {
  InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

  String l;

  while (( l = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    // do what you want with the line
  }

}

inputStream.close(); //close the file
  } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
//file doesnt exist
}
```

dont forget the imports!

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
```

Comment: what var is "in" ? is it a simply defined boolean?!

Answer (score 0):

Using `java.io.BufferedReader`, you can read a line at a time with the `readLine()` function. As you read each line, add it to an `ArrayList<String>`. Finally, there are methods in `ArrayList` that will help you copy the data out to an array, if an `ArrayList` doesn't suit your purpose.

As to reading an xls, file, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854947/android-office-library-doc-docx-xls-ppt-etc).