# How to open MS Office files in Android

Tags: android, api, ms-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Microsoft Office Library (.doc, .docx, .xls, .ppt, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854947/android-microsoft-office-library-doc-docx-xls-ppt-etc)

I have been searching for an API for android to open and view `.doc`, `.ppt`, `.docx` or `.pptx`.

I'm sure there should be one as there exist applications that can open these file format. I have found apache POI but it uses java awt which is not a part of android.

Even an API to convert these file format to `.pdf` will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a standard API for opening office files in Android. The applications you've found use an internal API for reading the files. They either do this in the device or they upload the file to a server, which is responsible for parsing the file and convert it to a format that is easier read from the Android client.

Comment: actually i was aiming to  make such a parser(like one with server)

Comment: can u please make clear what is an internal API, nad if it is there why cant i use it in my application.

Comment: By internal I mean proprietary. The easiest way will be to use a server-client architecture. Upload the file to a server, where a wealth of open APIs are available. Read the file and convert it to HTML or something similar. Send it back to the device in order to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do so if your phone comes with an application such as Quickoffice, and in those cases, you will be opening it in that application through your application.

[How to render PDF in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android)

[Android Microsoft Office Library (.doc, .docx, .xls, .ppt, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854947/android-office-library-doc-docx-xls-ppt-etc)

Comment: apache POI is not compatible with android