# In my application I want display contents of PDF or .DOCX (containg text and images ) so that it looks like an viewing android application?

Tags: android, pdf, doc

In my application I want display contents of .PDF or .DOCX (containg text and images ) so that it looks like an viewing  android application instead viewing it pdf or docx Reader ?

Answer (score 1):

to display a PDF, you could use Google Drive document viewer inside a webview to do so.

```
String pdf = "mypdfFile.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

works with .docx too, atleast on a native chrome browser, you should modify the webview to display it.

Comment: I am making an offline android application and problem is that there are a lot of images and text in my document and i want to display the same  in my app so came up with an idea to display an document instead of creating individual layouts because they are making apk size heavier

Comment: it will be far more heavy if you load big documents than if you use XML and java classes, as far as i know. being offline, i cannot think of any way of displaying embedded documents as if they were part of the application.

Comment: But if i am using images than APK size is growing more than using PDF. Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Your question has ever been asked on a lot of other posts, you can find some hints here for .PDF :

[PDF Library to rendering the PDF files in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096228/pdf-library-to-rendering-the-pdf-files-in-android)

And for .DOCX :

[How to open MS Office files in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250472/how-to-open-ms-office-files-in-android)

Comment: I integrated but the images were blurred I was unable to make it full screen. more issues and it feels like reading a document.