# How can I read/edit PowerPoint 2007/2010 files in Android?

Tags: android, api, ms-office, powerpoint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Microsoft Office Library (.doc, .docx, .xls, .ppt, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854947/android-microsoft-office-library-doc-docx-xls-ppt-etc)

I have been searching for an API for Android to read/edit `.ppt` and `.pptx` file formats.

I have tried Apache POI but it seems it does not support many things like wordart, special characters and shapes, etc. I have also tried Aspose API for Java. Is there any other API that I can use for this?

If there is an API that will convert these file formats to PDF or HTML, it would also solve my problem.

Any open source Java library will also be useful-- I can spend some time to make it compatible
with Android.