# Android API or Library for Microsoft Office files

Tags: android, open-source, jar, ms-office, openoffice.org

Does anyone know of an Android API or Library for viewing MS-Office's files (.doc, .ppt, etc.)?
I know this question brought up several time, but it was a long time ago, and I just wanted to know if something has changed?

I heard Open-Office is now available for android, but I couldn't find any external library...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: check out this questoin http://stackoverflow.com/q/4854947/582571

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use an Ms Office files you will use OpenOffice API ;) same same but different ...

[OpenOffice API](http://www.openoffice.org/api/)