# Any third party to provide the android library of rendering MS-office (word,ppt,excel)

Tags: android, ms-office

Any third party to provide the android library of rendering office ？
I need open the word,ppt,excel files in my apps.
I use the UIWebView in ios. But I can not find the way on Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Microsoft Office Library (.doc, .docx, .xls, .ppt, etc.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854947/android-microsoft-office-library-doc-docx-xls-ppt-etc)

Answer (score 0):

I found that Google Drive comes with an excellent document viewer, and you can simply send docs to it by intent. It renders all Office docs (so far as I have seen) quite well.